# How to change CMD's prompt theme and style?

Tags: bash, cmd

I am working on bash-like shell for Windows, but bashs have some customized inputs like:

Parrot OS bash:

```
┌──[%username%@%host%]-[cwd]
└──> #          [It has colours!]
```

Git Bash:

```
%username%@%host% MINGW64 ~
$
```

And more...

:EDIT

Sorry for unclear question. So there are hints and answers:

I called "input" in Windows CMD in those line where you type command, also called "prompt". And I took examples from Parrot OS bash and Git bash input examples, yea Parrot OS is Unix system and I am talking on Windows, I saw that it has special input which can be changed via .bashrc, but on Windows CMD doesn't has .bashrc, but it must have any options to change prompt but how to change that "C:\Path\To\Something>" style prompt to Parrot OS bash prompt style?
Is it ever possible?

Comment: And what? I am using minimal example!

Comment: I am asking how to change prompt's style in Windows cmd. In default it is:  'C:\Path\To\CWD>' and I want to change it as some of those examples in question and want to add colours too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to change CMD's input theme and stype?

It's called "prompt" or "command prompt" or "prompt string". In most *unix shells you edit the `PS1` or `PROMPT_COMMAND` variables. In NT cmd.exe you use the command [prompt](https://ss64.com/nt/prompt.html) to change the prompt string.

Comment: `I am talking about Windows, not Unix` - to be specific, `Parrot OS bash:` is part of your question and Parrot OS is a unix system. `Am I talking Chinese?` If you know what it's called, it looks like you did zero to no research on the topic. You asked "How to change CMD's input theme and style?"? What is "input theme", please define that. What is CMD's "style", please define that. Then you followed with examples of the prompt string in bash-like environments. Are they related to "style" and "input theme"? Your question is, still, unclear.

Comment: I would be tempted to delete my answer and downvote the question. This is one of the many reasons not to attempt to answer unclear, poorly-researched questions.

Comment: @KamilCuk `Parrot OS bash:` isn't part of my question, just example. Check question now!

Comment: Thanks @KamilCuk! Now I know how to change prompt.